# Is there a solution for controlling where packages are installed from in R?

Tags: r

This is a very specific issue.

Let's say I have two package repos, "valid" and "unvalidated". "valid" is a smaller repo with a curated set of packages which I have checked for quality in some way. "unvalidated" is just a mirror of CRAN.

Now most of the time I want to install a package from "valid" because I trust them more, but sometimes I really need to install a package from "unvalidated".

What I'd like to be able to do is for R to do the following logic when installing a package "A"

1. Does A exist on "valid"? If so, install the latest version (we can assume for now that valid will always have all the dependencies of any package on it)
2. If A does not exist on "valid", install the latest version from "unvalidated".
3. If when installing A you need to install any dependencies, follow the logic as above

The standard R installation will not do this; if you list more than one repo R will simply search for the latest version of an R package, rather than prefer it from a particular source.

Is there a solution to do this easily?

Comment: Maybe renv https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html in combination with carefully constructed lockfiles could help you. It is not really clear to me if this should be a general solution (for any machine) or if it is only for some local setup? I guess you could also try something along `option(repos = "repoA")` try installing and if it fails set `option(repos = "repoB")` and try again?

Comment: Or you write a wrapper around install.packages that tries it first with repos = valid and then switches to repos = unvalidated?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine something like this could work:

```r
# order matters, length does not
repos <- c("https://somewhere/validated/repo", "https://somewhere/unvalidated/repo")
pkgs <- c("pkg1", "pkg2", "pkg3")
for (repo in repos) {
  needpkgs <- setdiff(pkgs, rownames(installed.packages()))
  if (!length(needpkgs)) break
  install.packages(needpkgs, repos = repo)
}
# optional follow-up
needpkgs <- setdiff(pkgs, rownames(installed.packages()))
if (length(needpkgs)) warning("some packages were not found: ", toString(needpkgs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate it in a try-catch code:

```
valid <- "https://my.valid.repo"
unvalidated <- "https://some.cran.mirror"

custom_install <- function(package) {
    tryCatch({
        install.packages(package, repos = valid)
    }, error = function(err) {
        install.packages(package, repos = unvalidated)
    })
}
```